# How to crop image within specified dimension

Tags: html, css, image

On my woocommerce website each product has a thumbnail which is 600px x 600px, the images within this thumbnail are usually much bigger as they are watercolor paintings (e.g. 2000 x 2000). What I am trying to do is fit the image within 600x600 and fill the negative space with a white border.

Example (There is alot of white background around this 600x600 image) - 
[image]

I have tried to do this with CSS but it always mucks up the rest of my website. Is there any online tools that could achieve this or should I keep working on my CSS?

CSS -

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {  

    height: 330px;
    width: 330px;
    position: relative;

}  
.woocommerce ul.products li.product a img {  
    max-height: 90%;  
    max-width: 90%;  
    position: absolute;  
    top: 0;  
    bottom: 0;  
    left: 0;  
    right: 0;  
    margin: auto;  
    background: #3A6F9A;  
    border: 2px solid gray; 
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

HTML -

```
<li class="post-267 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail first instock shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-variable has-default-attributes has-children">
    <a href="http://localhost/testsite/?product=autumn-by-the-lake-copy" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link"><img width="3150" height="2253" src="http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Autumn-by-the-Lake-Carolyn-Judge-Watercolours.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog size-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="Autumn by the Lake Carolyn Judge Watercolours" title="Autumn by the Lake Carolyn Judge Watercolours" srcset="http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Autumn-by-the-Lake-Carolyn-Judge-Watercolours.jpg 3150w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Autumn-by-the-Lake-Carolyn-Judge-Watercolours-300x215.jpg 300w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Autumn-by-the-Lake-Carolyn-Judge-Watercolours-768x549.jpg 768w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Autumn-by-the-Lake-Carolyn-Judge-Watercolours-1024x732.jpg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 3150px) 100vw, 3150px" />
    <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Autumn By The Lake (Copy)</h2></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `object-fit: cover;` on the img(No IE support yet).

regarding the 'cover' value:

> The whole image is scaled down or expanded till it fills the box completely, the aspect ratio is maintained. This normally results in only part of the image being visible.

or

```
img{
  ...
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/1500/1000/city/Dummy-Text) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  ...
}
```

or

```
img{
  width: auto;
  height: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define image dimensions in Woocommerce >> Settings >> Products >> Display. Here after defining your required dimensions, you can regenerate the images. So, that it will not cause unnecessary load on system with loading more bigger images.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.ratio-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: calc(100% * 600 / 600); // If you want other ratio, for example 3x4, this line will be: `padding-bottom: calc(100% * 4 / 3)`
}
.img-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.img-wrapper img {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    /* Center alignment */
    margin: auto;
    top: -9999px;
    bottom: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
    right: -9999px;
}
.img-wrapper img.landscape { /* For images have natural width >= height */
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
.img-wrapper img.portrait { /* For images have natural width < height */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

**DEMO**

```
<div class="ratio-box">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img class="landscape" src="https://traxanhthainguyen.com/images/201703/van-hoa-uong-tra-cua-nguoi-viet.jpg" alt="demo">
    </div>
</div>
```

To determine automatically the image is landscape or portrait, we can use JavaScript. Full code: http://vanquyet.com/css-crop-and-center-image-with-the-specific-aspect-ratio.html

Hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom image sizes in wordpress using function 
`add_image_size( string $name, int $width, int $height, bool|array $crop = false )` 
[Read full documentation here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/)

Alernatively, 
go to WP-admin, navigate to WooCommerce-> Settings and the click Products tab and then click display.

You can add image size there. Don't forget to click hard crop in front of image sizes if you want images to be cropped.

After you, will need to Re-generate image sizes, using Re-generate image thumbnail plugin.

After getting desired image size, now you can handle every thing using css/html only.